# Best way to make an action x times without using a Handler?

Tags: android

I want to replace this function:

```
private void transmit(){
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Wait for the connection to stablish",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Log.d("BtSending", "run: Sending..");


            mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(superString,bluetoothGattCharacteristicHM_10);

            mHandler.postDelayed(this,250);

        }
    },1000);

}
```

for something more pretty, it works just fine but a friend told me that there was a more efficient way to do it, but i dont remember what he told me. Help me please, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlers are the recommended way to run recurring actions in quick succession. That doesn't mean you can't make the code a bit neater, though.

```
private final int MSG_TRANSMIT = 100;

private TransmitHandler handler = new TransmitHandler();

private void transmit() {
    //...

    handler.sendInitialTransmit();
}

public class TransmitHandler extends Handler {
    public TransmitHandler() {
        super(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_TRANSMIT:
                mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(superString,bluetoothGattCharacteristicHM_10);
                if (shouldTransmit) sendTransmit(); //shouldTransmit is an arbitrary boolean so you can stop the loop when needed
                break;
        }
    }

    public void sendInitialTransmit() {
        sendEmptyMessageAtTime(MSG_TRANSMIT, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 1000);
    }

    public void sendTransmit() {
        sendEmptyMessageAtTime(MSG_TRANSMIT, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 250); //where 250 is your delay
    }

    public void cancelTransmit() {
        removeMessages(MSG_TRANSMIT); //if MSG_TRANSMIT is currently queued to be executed, calling cancelTrasmit() will remove it from the queue
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it could be better using a service instead?

Comment: How would you use a Service? Services are just components that can run constantly in the background. You'd still need to put something in the Service to run an action every x seconds.

Comment: Sorry I think I miss to mention a data, I need to send it every x second infinite times. But this actually answered my question haha thanks